Question: Why does the Math.Round method in C# round numbers unexpectedly, and how can this be fixed?
I ran into an issue with number rounding in C#. At first glance, the Math.Round() method seems to work correctly, but when rounding certain numbers, the results are unexpected.
Example:

For the number 3.1455543, calling Math.Round(3.1455543, 2) returns the expected result — 3.15.
However, for the number 3.1447456, the same method Math.Round(3.1447456, 2) returns 3.14, which is not what I expected (I want 3.15).

Can anyone explain why this happens? I understand that the Math.Round method uses "banker's rounding" (round half to even), but why does this specific case not follow the expected rounding behavior?
Is there a solution to this problem so that numbers round according to standard mathematical rules instead of the "banker's rounding" method?

But with 3.1447456 if look from the third decimal place you have 0.0047456 which is less than 0.005. Why do you expect it to be rounded up (to 3.15) ?

What standard mathematical rules will round up 3.1447456 to 3.15?

Your expectation is plainly wrong. If for whatever reason you need that behavior anyway, you'll probably need to implement that yourself or find a matching predefined rounding  strategy.

Bankers rounding would only make a difference when rounding 3.1450000. For your value only the "regular" rules apply: round towards nearest, which is 3.14.
FYI Math.Round(3.1447456, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity) does give 3.15, as would any number greater than 3.14 (such as 3.140001) - it's effectively Math.Ceiling, but with (in this case 2) decimals.

It references the 3rd Number From the nearest 2 Decimal Places.
Math.Round(number, neareast)
number is the number
nearest is the decimal place being rounded
(nearest + 1) is what determines if it rounds up or down
Any (nearest + 1) thats greater than 5 rounds (nearest) up by 1

So?! What do I have to do with it? How can I get 3.15 if I have 3.1444756?

Theres a few ways to do it.  The best way is probably a float method with a for loop.  You should stack Math.Round recursively.

Can you clarify what you mean by "float method with a for loop" and "stack Math.Round recursively"?
